# Laravel 5.2: Filter route group based on the domain name

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, middleware

I have an application, which uses multiple domains:
1. the main domain
2. domains for different sections of the site (each user can have a domain for his own page, saved in the user_profile).

I need a route group, which I want to be available only for the main domain, and an other group which will be available for the other domains. The first group will not be available for the other domains and the second group will not be available for the main domain. How can I implement this?

A middleware is the solution? How can I access the current domain in a middleware?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the current host, which can be used in your middleware:

`$request->server->get('HTTP_HOST')`

You could actually just use the a route group like (in your routes.php):

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{sitedomain}'], function()
{
    // routes here

})->where('sitedomain', '.+\.your_domain_regex\.com$');
```

Comment: and if does not match the domain, I can throw an abort('404') ?

Comment: @Zoli See my updated answer, you could achieve this using a route group.

Comment: This is available also in the controllers? $request->server->get('HTTP_HOST')

Comment: @Zoli You can use `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` in your controller and inject `Request $request` into your method like:

`public function index(Request $request) {
    dd($request->server->get('HTTP_HOST'));
}`